# Efficient overloading with generics

Tags: .net, generics, overloading

My question is half stylistic, half functional. I'm rewriting a library and trying to compact it down as much as possible. (It takes a path and reads values into a ByRef variable.) Previously it looked like this:

`Public Sub Read(ByVal name As String, ByRef values(,) As Integer)`

`Public Sub Read(ByVal name As String, ByRef values(,,) As Long)`

Etc etc... There were about **30** of these, including scalar versions. Nightmare to update.

Every method was overloaded by type and rank. I'm redoing this system with generics, but I'm running into an issue. The following methods won't compile:

`Public Sub Read(Of T)(ByVal name as String, ByRef values As T)`

`Public Sub Read(Of T)(ByVal name as String, ByRef values As T())`

`Public Sub Read(Of T)(ByVal name as String, ByRef values As T(,))`

`Public Sub Read(Of T)(ByVal name as String, ByRef values As T(,,))`

It's fairly obvious why it won't compile; type 'T' could easily be considered an Array, and the compiler doesn't know whether to choose the first or the second overload. (Note: This system works as you'd expect if there **isn't** a scalar version of the overloaded Read methods.)

So, I'm left with a conundrum. I don't know the best way to design these overloads so I use the least code while maintaining as much backwards compatibility with existing code using this library. (We're using it strictly in-house, so I **could** change any code using my library, but I'd rather keep the signatures the same as much as possible.)

Basically, is there a way to design my overloads like I've shown? Can I explicitly tell the compiler that I want the top overload to only be used for scalar inputs? If not, what's the best design? I'm open to any creative ideas.

Thanks

Comment: That's strange, in `C#` with `.NET 3.5` that is not an issue, compiles and runs with no problem. Anyway, try to do as in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to make your first overload to take only structures (if you're using only numeric values in your case).

```
Public Sub Read(Of T As Structure)(ByVal name as String, ByRef values As T)
```

Maybe this can do the overload selection since arrays are not structures.

Another thing to do, a little uglier, is to make all array overloads with a different name, and scalar with its own name.
Inside the scalar version, you check if `T is Array`, count it's dimensions and call the propper array overload.